# Disable Heroku Router Logs

Tags: heroku

I've written a Heroku app, that's a very simple API. A number of `GET` requests are made to it with sensitive information amongst their parameters. It would be preferable to have Heroku not log this sensitive information.

*Is there any way to have Heroku **not** log requests or better yet, truncate the path so it contains no parameters?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do it. The usual answer is to `POST` the sensitive information rather than use `GET`, but I'm guessing that's not an option for you.

Comment: Quick update - I just e'd Heroku support this very question, and there's still no way to do this.

Comment: 6 years later → Heroku still has no option to disable or at least anonymize logs. Salesforce support does not want to answer tickets regardings this issue, now a back and forth since 2020/08. Due to this negative effect on data privacy I removed all my apps from Heroku.

Answer (score 8):

Using `heroku logs --source app` will only show the logs of you app. 
[heroku logging](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)

Comment: This command displays the logs, however it doesn't prevent Heroku from logging parameters.

Comment: This does not answer the question and should probably be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone is still searching for this. Papertrail now supports Log filters.

Just go to Papertrail > Dashboard > lower right corner > Filter logs.

You can use a regular expression like this:

```
heroku\/router
```

and papertrail will ignore all heroku/router logs. This however does not prevent Heroku from emitting those logs altogether, you can still see live `heroku/router`  logs by going to your app's dashboard and clicking "More"> "View Logs.

It can significantly reduce costs though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and as I didn't find a solution.
So I'll let you know my **workaround** for PHP **Laravel 6.3** application on Heroku.

1. Activate Papertrail addon (free with "Wayne" plan)
2. Show web app output
3. Filter for "application" (and environment, in my case "staging"
4. "Save search" -> Replace existing search -> "web app output"

Hope this helps others.

Comment: how to js or no?